# Why this sequence converges to $0$ and not to $1$ in probability?

Tags: convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

I didn't understand why this sequence bellow converges to $0$ in probability?

[image]

Shouldn't this sequence converge to $1$ in probability?

This is the definition of convergence in probability:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Write $X_n=I(A_n)$ where $I$ is the indicator function and $A_n$ are the sequence of sets given. Given $0<\varepsilon<1$
$$
P(|X_n|>\varepsilon)=\lambda(A_n)\to 0
$$
as $n\to \infty$. If $\varepsilon\geq 1$, then trivially $P(|X_n|>\varepsilon)=0$.

Comment: this is so difficult to me understand.. What is $\lambda$? I believe that $X_{n}$ is always one. To converge to zero, somehow this sequence has to take de direction of zero. But how?

Comment: Following this reasoning I can accept that this sequence does not converge almost certainly to zero, because it is always 1, and thus, there is no point convergence to zero. But this sequence also converges to 1 almost surely?

Comment: @Laura $\lambda$ is lebesgue measure

Answer (score 0):

The definition of '$1_{A_n}$ converges in probability to $0$' is 'For all $\varepsilon > 0$, $\lim P(|1_{A_n} -0| >\varepsilon) = 0$'

The $\varepsilon$'s in question actually depend on whether or not they are greater than $1$.

**Let us consider each case**, and show $\lim P(|1_{A_n} -0| >\varepsilon) = 0$ in each case.

Each case begins as follows: $\lim P(|1_{A_n} -0| >\varepsilon) = \lim P(|1_{A_n}| >\varepsilon)$

$ = \lim P(1_{A_n} >\varepsilon) = \lim [P(1_{A_n} >\varepsilon)] = \lim [1- P(1_{A_n} \le \varepsilon)] = 1- \lim [P(1_{A_n} \le \varepsilon)]$

1. *Case 1*: $0<\varepsilon<1$

   - Observe that for $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, we have that $\{1_{A_n} \le \varepsilon\} = \{1_{A_n} = 0\}$. Then

$$1- \lim P(1_{A_n} \le \varepsilon) = 1- \lim P(1_{A_n} = 0) = 1- \lim P(1_{A_n^C} = 1) = 1- \lim P(A_n^C)$$

$$= 1- \lim [P(A_n^C)] = \lim [1- P(A_n^C)] = \lim [P(A_n)] = 0$$

2. *Case 2*: $\varepsilon=1$

   - Observe that for $\varepsilon = 1$, we have that $\{1_{A_n} \le 1\} = \{1_{A_n} \le \varepsilon \}$. Observe also that $\{1_{A_n} \le 1\} = [1_{A_n} = 1] \cup [1_{A_n} = 0] = \Omega$ Then

$$1- \lim [P(1_{A_n} \le \varepsilon)] = 1- \lim P(1_{A_n} \le 1) = 1- \lim P([1_{A_n} = 1] \cup [1_{A_n} = 0]) = 1- \lim P(A_n \cup A_n^C) = 1- \lim P(\Omega) = 1 - 1 = 0$$

$$= 1- \lim [P(A_n^C)] = \lim [1- P(A_n^C)] = \lim [P(A_n)] = 0$$

3. *Case 3*: $\varepsilon>1$

   - Observe that we still have for $\varepsilon > 1$ that $\{1_{A_n} \le 1\} = \{1_{A_n} \le \varepsilon \}$. Observe also that we still have that $\{1_{A_n} \le \varepsilon \} = \{1_{A_n} \le 1\} = [1_{A_n} = 1] \cup [1_{A_n} = 0]$ Then

$$1- \lim [P(1_{A_n} \le \varepsilon)] = 1- \lim P(1_{A_n} \le 1) = 1- \lim P([1_{A_n} = 1] \cup [1_{A_n} = 0]) = 1- \lim P(A_n \cup A_n^C) = 1- \lim P(\Omega) = 1 - 1 = 0$$

**Therefore**, regardless of the $\varepsilon$, we end up with $$\lim P(|1_{A_n} -0| >\varepsilon) =0$$